# XenApp Web interface: User loging from two different browsers or machines -> Disconnected session

Tags: citrix, xenapp

I have an issue with our new Citrix XenApp 6.5 deployment with Web Interface 5.4 and CSG 3.3.1

We have external users who share the same access (we charge them by access so they don't order more than they need and manage that internally). This setup was working just fine with XenApp 4.5: users could log into the web interface twice but, when they tried to access the same published app, they would not be allowed to go through and be greeted with a "you have reached the limit of allowed sessions for this resource" dialog.

Now, with 6.5 (and Citrix web interface 5.4), we have a different behavior: as soon as the second user logs into the WI, the first user's session is disconnected. Pretty often (but, apparently, not every time) the second user will automatically reconnected to the first user's session.

I suspect that this behavior is due to the session reliability parameter but I'd like a confirmation.

More important: If it is indeed session reliability that is causing this behavior, is it possible to maintain its advantages (mostly ability to seamlessly reconnect THE SAME RECEIVER to its session in case of network glitch or if we restart the CSG) without having "auto reconnection at web interface level" enabled ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, after asking the question I found the solution on my own :/

In case anyone ends up here, the solution is this:

Go in the web interface management tool, select the web site, right-click and select "workspace control" and there select the "Reconnect only to disconnected sessions" radio (I did it for both auto reconnect and the reconnect button)

Comment: I've taken "Solved" out - just mark this answer as correct when you can